# XCode performs custom behavior .sh script failed with The operation couldn’t be completed,Exec format error

Tags: xcode, shell, applescript

As you can see near the screenshot [*Logs infos pic*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YezFV.png), the .sh Script can run normal inside terminal, but failed to run via Xcode custom behavior, Is there missing some configuration? I've Googled a lot of infos. still can't solve it. I really need someone's help. Thanks

XCode version: Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)

Comment: Show the script to be able to help.

Comment: please click the link [logs infos pic]. you will see a screenshot with .script

Comment: the .sh script file must in local project dir. otherwise Xcode can't find the script to run. there will be prompt the error "The operation couldn’t be completed,Exec format error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `New Run Script Phase` in your projects `Build Phases` to run a Shell script. You do not need to `open -a Terminal`:

[image]

---

Update:

How I understand your comment, your actual question is how to get the Xcode project directory. Xcode provides a enviromental variable for this, `${PROJECT_DIR}`:

[image]

prints:

[image]

You can find a list of Xcodes enviromental variables [in this repo](https://gist.github.com/gdavis/6670468) and helpful information [in Apples documentation](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/itcaec37c2a6).

Comment: thanks for your response, But I just want to know if XCode could configure custom behavior and wake up Terminal.  cause to find the current project  path inside XCode is a suck thing.... I hope there is a convenient way.

Comment: I have updated the answer according to how to get the "project path" and why it is not such a "suck thing" :-)

Comment: I can't vote for you, cause my reputation doesn't get 15. :(